# Grails formRemote duplicate submission

Tags: grails

I know there is a way to use withForm and useToken to prevent duplicate form submission in Grails. However that is only for normal form and there is no such attribute for ajax call on server side.

I am wondering anyone did the same for formRemote in Grails before?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you don't want JS fix for this, but as far as I know you can call a java script function  on loading of the formRemote and disable form submit button to avoid duplicate submission.

and then redirect or something; whatever you can do with on success or on failure/error.